# Generics, Casting, and ArrayList (oh my)

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, casting

I've just started working with Java for a Data Strutures and Algorithms class (my background is mainly C++) and I've run into something quite clunky in my first assignment.

We were to create a "set" data structure - a bag that does not accept duplicates. From what I can tell, this is essentially just an `ArrayList` with some extra checks made during the `add()`.

It all works, but I was forced to do something quite clunky when returning the set as an array:

```
class Set<T> implements SetInterface<T> {

    // Properties
    private ArrayList<T> _set = new ArrayList<T>();

    // Methods
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return this._set.toArray();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SetInterface<Integer> mySet = new Set<Integer>();

    // set is filled, other tests are performed...

    Object[] myArray = mySet.toArray().clone();

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        System.out.print((int)myArray[i] + " ");
}
```

I originally tried to return an array of type `T[]` but that threw `ClassCastException`:

```
public T[] toArray() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] temp = (T[])new Object[this._set.size()];
    temp = this._set.toArray(temp);
    return temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SetInterface<Integer> mySet = new Set<Integer>();

    // set is filled, other tests are performed...

    Integer[] myArray = mySet.toArray().clone();

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
}
```

Now, my solution up top works, but it just... feels wrong. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this? That is, is there a way to avoid having to cast each element in the array after the fact?

Hope this is clear.

Comment: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collection.java#Collection.toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29

Comment: @SLaks, from what I can tell the issue here is that I'm using generics. `ArrayList.toArray(T[] a)` works great with specific types for `a`, but chokes when `a` is a generic.

Comment: You should make your function take a `T[]`, just like that does.

Comment: Yet another erasure question. There's a reason the standard Java collections have to return `Object[]` from their zero-argument `toArray` methods.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right about the multitude of erasure questions. My question is more about whether this is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, as I'm very new to Java and its best practices.

Comment: If you use a `list` to implement a `set` (thinking that it's is _just_ a matter of some checks during `add`) , won't your `add` method become _very slow_ after a while, say 1M elements? (And I don't think this has to do anything with Java or C++).

Comment: @KedarMhaswade absolutely, since `add()` has to check the entire set for possible duplicates before adding the new element. I'm pretty sure this assignment is more of an intro to Java than anything else, as avoiding duplicates in an unordered list becomes unwieldy, as you pointed out.

Comment: It would be very instructive for you to examine the [GrepCode implementation of `HashSet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashSet.java?av=f)